# Layout breaks when translating Meta to Portuguese

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, localization

When I load [Meta translated into Portuguese](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&tl=pt-BR&u=https://meta.stackoverflow.com/&usg=ALkJrhhKVNwLswvhkUAU4G7cMZzjAbw_Rg) by Chrome, the layout breaks like in the following screenshot:

[image: broken translated layout]

Comment: I haven't seen that. What browser are you using?

Comment: my browser is Chrome

Comment: Platform and version?

Comment: I use Windows Vista and the version of Chrome is 32.0.1700.107 m

Comment: I'm not sure that layout issues caused by translating the page in Chrome are really addressable.

Comment: How wide is your display in pixels?

Comment: i have 1600px in my laptop

Comment: Confirmed, it does the same thing for me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Did you use a similar setup?

Comment: I went to translate.google.com, typed in http://meta.stackoverflow.com, selected portugese, and clicked the Translate button.  I'm using Chrome.  I have a 1920X1200 display.

Comment: That reproduced it for me too.

Answer (score 5):

A translated site will essentially re-write bits of the pages on the fly, messing the layout (words that mean the same in different languages have different lengths, so simply changing the rendered language will not account for the need to change the layout as well).

This is not something that we can simply support.

[Stack Overflow em Portuguese](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) has its own [Meta site](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com).